como hacer que Script.ps1 funcione bien en segundo plano
El siguiente código es un script en powershell el cual bloquea el ordenador cuando se ingresa un dispositivo usb que no esta en la lista blanca. El código funciona de manera correcta si lo ejecuto desde la consola de powershell o desde el powershell ise, pero deja de funcionar si cierro la consola de powerShell. Quiero que mi condigo se ejecute en segundo plano sin tener que tener la consola de powershell activa, pero no realiza su funcion cuando uso Start-Job -ScriptBlock {Codigo}. Alguien sabe porque o como solucionarlo.
Muchas gracias
#$DebugPreference = "Continue"
$global:white_list         = "USBSTOR\DISK&VEN_KINGSTON&PROD_DATATRAVELER_3.0&REV_\40B0767E2097F4C0D6551CEF&0"
$global:white_list_iron    = "USBSTOR\DISK&VEN_AS&PROD_MASS_STORAGE&REV_\6&AB70B92&0"
$global:white_list_maquina = "USBSTOR\DISK&VEN_SMI&PROD_USB_DISK&REV_1100\6&20051FEA&0"
$global:camara = "USBSTOR\DISK&VEN_FLIR&PROD_REMOVABLE&REV_1.00\7&32560D5&0"



function global:Get-DevicesID {
    Get-WmiObject Win32_USBControllerDevice | Foreach-Object { [Wmi]$_.Dependent | Select -ExpandProperty DeviceID }
    }

function global:Check-NewDevice {
    $global:actual_dev = Get-DevicesID
    Write-Debug ("New Devices = "+$global:actual_dev)
    $global:test = Compare-Object $global:actual_dev $global:init_dev
    if($test) {
        if(
           ($global:test.InputOBJECT -notcontains $global:white_list) -and 
           ($global:test.InputOBJECT -notcontains $global:white_list_iron)-and
           ($global:test.InputOBJECT -notcontains $global:white_list_maquina) -and
           ($global:test.InputOBJECT -notcontains $global:camara)   
          ){$true}
        }


    }

function global:Run-Action {
    Write-Debug "Run-Action"
    if(Check-NewDevice) {
        Write-Debug "Accion"
        rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation
        #Restart-Computer -Force
        }
    }



$global:init_dev = Get-DevicesID
Write-Debug ("Init Devices = "+$init_dev)

$query_event = "SELECT * FROM Win32_DeviceChangeEvent WHERE EventType = 2"
Register-WMIEvent -SourceIdentifier "USB_Monitor" -Query $query_event -Action { Run-Action } | Write-Debug


y ejecutarlo como un tarea al iniciar windows?

no funciona tampoco, porque pareciera que el script se ejecutara y cerrara automáticamente, y no sigue activo

quisiera que al ejecutarlo, permanezca activo funcionando hasta que apague el computador, sin tener que tener la consola de powershell abierta

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Para ejecutar el script en segundo plano sin mantener la consola de PowerShell abierta, usa Register-ScheduledTask para crear una tarea programada que ejecute el script automáticamente en el fondo.
Guarda el script en un archivo script.ps1 y ejecuta la tarea programada:
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "powershell.exe" -Argument "-File C:\ruta\al\script.ps1"
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartup
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "MonitorUSB"


Si. me funciono. Muchas Gracias

¡Qué bien funciona! Ha sido un placer poder ayudarte. Por favor, marca la respuesta como resuelta, así mantendremos el sitio conciso y limpio.
